# Auto-type in html input

Tags: html

I want to have two input fields. It should be possible to type in one of them, but the other one should be hidden. whatever we type in the first field should be auto-typed in the hidden one. Is this possible?

Comment: You can do that with JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `type='hidden'` for the second input

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenInput')

input.addEventListener('input', ({ target: { value } }) => hiddenInput.value = value)
```

```html
<input id='input'/>
<input id='hiddenInput'/>
```